# XML XSD Schema - Import XML SQLXMLBulkLoad with Attribute

Tags: xml, sql-server-2005, import, xsd, sqlxml

I am trying to import a big XML file into my SQL Server 2005.

Let's have a look to a snippet of my XML file:

```
<Details>
    <Title>I am a title</Title>
    <Manufacturer ....
</Details>
```

My xsd looks like:

```
<xs:element name="Details" sql:is-constant="1">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title" sql:field="Title" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Manufacturer" sql:field="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" />
            ...
         </xs:sequence>
     </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

That works fine, but now I want to show you the weird part of the xml:

```
<Images>
    <Img Name="Adv">
        <URL>TARGET URL</URL>
        <Width>a width ....</Width>
    </Img>
    <Img Name="Img30">
        <URL>a URL again</URL>
        <Width>...</Width>
    </Img>
    <Img Name="Img60">
        <URL>......</URL>
        <Width>..</Width>
</Images>
```

How can I get the value `(TARGET URL)` from `Images > Img.Adv > URL` ?

How can I consider the attribute `(Name="Adv")`?

I am at the end of my knowledge, please help!

Comment: Using a XSD to *get* a value doesn't make any sense. What do you mean? Do you want to know how to declare that structure? What is the context for the `Images` element? Is it inside `Details`. Do they both have a parent in common?

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to know how to declare the XML fragment you showed using XSD. This `<xs:element>` block will validate the example you posted, assuming that the `URL` element accepts an `URI` (unvalidated), the `Width` accepts any decimal (floating-point), and you can have an unlimited amount of `Img` child elements, but a minimum of one:

```
<xs:element name="Images">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Img" maxOccurs="unbounded">
                <xs:complexType>
                    <xs:sequence>
                        <xs:element name="URL" type="xs:anyURI" />
                        <xs:element name="Width" type="xs:decimal"/>
                    </xs:sequence>
                    <xs:attribute name="Name" type="xs:string" />
                </xs:complexType>
            </xs:element>
        </xs:sequence>

    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

You can change the `Width` type to `xs:integer` to limit widths to ints, or to `xs:string` if it contains text such as a unit (`200px`). You can also add restrictions to validate the URL and check if it has a valid image extension, if it starts with `http`, etc. as well as restrictions to limit widths.

You didn't specify where your `Image` element was nested. Assuming it's inside `Details` following the existing tags, you would add a reference like this:

```
<xs:element name="Details">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:element name="Title" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element name="Manufacturer" type="xs:string" />
            <xs:element ref="Images" />
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>
```

Or paste the entire `xs:element` definition there.